# How to turn a flowSet into a dataframe or matrix?

Tags: r

I read 10 FCS files into a single flowSet. Because I need to calculate the ratio of 561-C-A/488-B-A for each single flowframe inside the flowSet, I think I need to turn this flowSet into a dataframe or matrix.

But, how to turn a flowSet into a dataframe or matrix?

I hope I have made it clear. Thank you very much for your answers! Appreciate!